# Linker Error - Not sure what it is not linking

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have been trying to figure out what is not linked or declared correctly in my code. I am writing a simple game engine in C++ for learning purposes and am trying to create a state machine. The linker error has something to do with unordered_list, list, or map. I am not sure which. The error is for the constructor with two arguments, which are two typedefs and is included in the code I show, the error happens when I call that constructor.

IState.h

```
#ifndef ZX_STATE_H
#define ZX_STATE_H

#include "coreDefines.h"
#include "zxstring.h"
ZX_NS_START

class IState
{
    tstring pm_name;
public:
    const tstring& name();
    virtual ~IState() = default;
    virtual void Pre() = 0;
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    virtual void Post() = 0;
};

ZX_NS_END
#endif
```

IStateMachine.h

```
#ifndef ZX_ISTATEMACHINE_H
#define ZX_ISTATEMACHINE_H
#include "object.h"
#include "zxstring.h"
#include "IState.h"
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
#include <list>

ZX_NS_START
typedef std::map<tstring, IState*> StateMap;
typedef std::unordered_set<tstring> StateSet;
typedef std::list<StateSet> RunOrder;
class IStateMachine : object, IState
{
public:
    const tstring defaultState = T("zx default state");

    IStateMachine();
    IStateMachine(RunOrder** runOrder, StateSet** states);
    virtual ~IStateMachine();
    void Add(IState* state);
    void Remove(IState* state);

private:
    StateMap pm_states;
    RunOrder** pm_runOrder;
    StateSet** pm_activeStates;

    void Pre() override;
    void Run() override;
    void Post() override;

    void SetUpDefaultState();
    class DefaultState: IState
    {
        IStateMachine* pm_parent;
    public:
        DefaultState();
        explicit DefaultState(IStateMachine* parent);
        void Pre() override;
        void Run() override;
        void Post() override;
    };
};

ZX_NS_END
#endif
```

IStateMachine.cpp

```
#include "IStateMachine.h"
USINGZX;

IStateMachine::IStateMachine(): pm_states(StateMap()), pm_runOrder(nullptr), pm_activeStates(nullptr)
{
    SetUpDefaultState();
}

IStateMachine::IStateMachine(RunOrder** runOrder, StateSet** states) : pm_states(StateMap()), pm_runOrder(runOrder), pm_activeStates(states)
{
    SetUpDefaultState();
}

IStateMachine::~IStateMachine()
{
    delete pm_states[defaultState];
}


void IStateMachine::Add(IState* state)
{
    pm_states.insert(std::make_pair(state->name(), state));
}

void IStateMachine::Remove(IState* state)
{
    pm_states.erase(state->name());
}


void IStateMachine::Pre()
{
    pm_states[defaultState]->Pre();
}

void IStateMachine::Run()
{
    pm_states[defaultState]->Run();
}

void IStateMachine::Post()
{
    pm_states[defaultState]->Post();
}

void IStateMachine::SetUpDefaultState()
{
    DefaultState* def = new DefaultState(this);
    pm_states.insert(std::make_pair(defaultState, (IState*)def));
}

IStateMachine::DefaultState::DefaultState() :pm_parent(nullptr)
{
}

IStateMachine::DefaultState::DefaultState(IStateMachine* parent): pm_parent(parent)
{
}

void IStateMachine::DefaultState::Pre()
{
    for(const auto& states : **pm_parent->pm_runOrder)
    {
        for(const auto& runState : states)
        {
            pm_parent->pm_states[runState]->Pre();
        }
    }
}

void IStateMachine::DefaultState::Run()
{
    for(const auto& states: **pm_parent->pm_runOrder)
    {
        for(const auto& runState : states)
        {
            pm_parent->pm_states[runState]->Run();
        }
    }
}

void IStateMachine::DefaultState::Post()
{
    for (const auto& states : **pm_parent->pm_runOrder)
    {
        for (const auto& runState : states)
        {
            pm_parent->pm_states[runState]->Post();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the long...looong error message

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Zx::IStateMachine::IStateMachine(class std::list,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > > > * *,class std::unordered_set,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > * *)" (??0IStateMachine@Zx@@QAE@PAPAV?$list@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PAPAV?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall TestStateMachine::TestStateMachine(class std::list,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > > > * *,class std::unordered_set,class std::allocator >,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > * *)" (??0TestStateMachine@@QAE@PAPAV?$list@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PAPAV?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@2@@Z)

I can usually figure these out pretty easily but for what ever reason this one is stumping me.(Maybe something to do with the unreadable type in the error message)

I don't believe this will be of any consequence, however, here is the test code that invokes the linker error

StateMachineTest.cpp

```
class TestStateMachine : zx IStateMachine
{
public:
    TestStateMachine(zx RunOrder** order, zx StateSet** active) : zx IStateMachine(order, active)
    {

    }
};

TEST_CLASS(StateMachineTest)
{
public:
    TEST_METHOD(IStateMachineTest)
    {
        auto* order = new zx RunOrder();
        auto* active = new zx StateSet();



        TestStateMachine test = TestStateMachine(&order, &active);
    }

};
```

Comment: It appears `IStateMachine.cpp` is not included in your build.

Comment: How are you compiling/what is the compiler command?

Comment: Another possibility: `IStateMachine.h` puts the class into namespace `zx` conditionally, apparently based on some macro. But `StateMachineTest.cpp` refers to `zx::IStateMachine` unconditionally. Could it be that the conditions under which the two source files are compiled are different, and as a result, one source thinks the class is in namespace `zx` and the other believes it to be in the global namespace?

Comment: I just tested it with a static variable defined in IStateMachine.h and declared in IStateMachine.cpp, unfortunately this is not the case as it linked that variable just fine.

Comment: The zx is a shorthand for easy changing of namespace names, it does nothing conditionally I just think it looks nicer and was just playing with macros anyways lol.

Comment: looks nicer, playing around with macros? I don't think so, try removing the macros and doing things the normal way. Will at least eliminate one possibility for the error.

Comment: Double-check those macros (or better still, get rid of them). I still suspect that the two source files don't agree on what namespace the class is in.

Comment: #define zx Zx:: that is all the macro does, the project is simple at this point I know it has nothing to do with the namespace.

Comment: I have removed the macros with no change in the error.

Comment: @JoeMccane i removed all your macro stuff, and `#include`s with missing header files, provided a replacement for `tstring` like `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` and an implementation for `const tstring& IState::name() { return pm_name; }` and the code compiles without error.

Comment: ty swordfish you allowed me to point the problem to the tstring macro. as soon as I removed that it worked. I have to figure out the problem that has before continuing. Once again tyvm! Everyone thanks for you time you helped me out a lot.

Comment: if you add that as an answer @Swordfish I will accept it as an answer thanks again.

Comment: quick question about the problem. It seems the problem comes with the typedef declaration std::unordered_set<tstring> StateSet, why would that be the case, and when I substitute the macro with what the macro will compile down to it works. lol this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @JoeMccane I'd suggest you put together a [mcve] and ask a new question for that.

Comment: I actually will do that. I am actually very curious about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all your macro stuff, and `#include`s with missing header files, provided a replacement for `tstring` like `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` and an implementation for `const tstring& IState::name() { return pm_name; }` and the code compiles without error.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the problem was with the tstring macro, for somereason in typedef std::unordered_set<tstring> StateSet it causes the linker to throw an error for that type, even though tstring will compile down to std::string, which if substituted will compile fine.

Comment: Please, keep yourself from the hassle that comes when playing with macros. For eg. "The zx is a shorthand for easy changing of namespace names," can easily be achieved with `namespace foo = bar;`.

Comment: well the tstring macro is actually needed, it allows for multibyte and Unicode encoding. But I know I shouldn't be playing with macros, but that is how I learn, playing with fire and figuring out the consequences lol.

Comment: @JoeMccane I guess you are on Windows? `#include <tchar.h>` and use the typedef from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `USINGZX` is `using namespace zx;` then this code does not define `IStateMachine::IStateMachine` in the `zx` namespace, it's in the global namespace.

```
USINGZX;

IStateMachine::IStateMachine(): pm_states(StateMap()), pm_runOrder(nullptr), pm_activeStates(nullptr)
{
    SetUpDefaultState();
}
```

If you want to define `IStateMachine::IStateMachine` in the `zx` namespace then you've either got to say

```
zx::IStateMachine::IStateMachine(): pm_states(StateMap()), pm_runOrder(nullptr), pm_activeStates(nullptr)
{
    SetUpDefaultState();
}
```

or

```
namespace zx {

IStateMachine::IStateMachine(): pm_states(StateMap()), pm_runOrder(nullptr), pm_activeStates(nullptr)
{
    SetUpDefaultState();
}

}
```

Comment: I tried that fix and unfortunately that is not the problem. Anyways, the declaration does not need to be declared in the namespace, only when defined. When I put using namespace Zx; it acts as if you are inside the namespace when calling or referencing variables/functions, this only not the case when defining them. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I also know this isn't the case because I have other classes that are set up the same way with no problems.